# Color picker option in Javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, color-picker

I was looking without success for some function in javascript that replicates the operation of the paint'Color picker option'.

The idea is to capture the hexadecimal code of the colors. 
It is not a color palette, I need to extract the color of any elements.  Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Check out https://github.com/sstrudeau/jquery-dropper

Comment: Easiest way is to copy the page to a canvas and get the color of the pixel on the canvas

Comment: Yes, the point is that I want to leave the function inside my website, so I need the code to replicate it.

Comment: I checked github.com/sstrudeau/jquery-dropper but it doesn't seem to work anymore.